# Why my image/video metadata is being deleted? How can i save custom information in my files?

Tags: android, image, video, metadata, android-mediaplayer

I'm doing some experiments with the MediaStore class, saving my images and videos with custom data to read it later. It works fine, I find the way to set the parameters to my media items and I'm able to read them in my phone.

For example, I'm recording a video in fastmotion and to save the information to make my app "know" that it is a fastmotion video to make some custom UI stuffs, I add a text in my `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION` field.

It works fine, but if I copy my file to my computer, or other phone and I try to read the metadata again, everything is empty least:

```
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE
```

How can avoid this? Do you have some other idea to save a custom info in my files to read it later with a different application?

Right now I'm saving this data:

```
 static final String[] QUERY_PROJECTION = {
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,           // 0, int
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE,         // 1, string
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE,     // 2, string
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,    // 3, int
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, // 4, int
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,          // 5, string
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION,   // 6, int, 0, 90, 180, 270
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.WIDTH,         // 7, int
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.HEIGHT,        // 8, int
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE,          // 9, long
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LATITUDE,      // 10, double
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LONGITUDE      // 11, double
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION    // 12, String
    };
```

If necessary, I'd be open also to another way to save additional information in the files to read it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I add a text in my MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION field.

This adds a value in a database. It does not modify your video.

> It works fine, but if I copy my file to my computer, or other phone and I try to read the metadata again, everything is empty

The data in `MediaStore` is not somehow stuffed into the file. For example, setting the value in the `DESCRIPTION` column in `MediaStore` for a text (`.txt`) file does not somehow modify the text in that file to contain the `DESCRIPTION`.

> Do you have some other idea to save a custom info in my files to read it later with a different application?

Modify your file to contain your desired information.

Comment: and how can i modify it? I tried to modify the exif of my video/image but it doesnt work

Comment: @FranciscoDurdinGarcia: I would suggest that you open up a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide the code where you are modifying the EXIF headers and explain, in detail, what specific symptoms are implied by "doesnt work".